# Angular 7 initiate browser file download from server with Authorization

Tags: javascript, angular, download, jwt

I need to implement following functionality using Angular 7 and I have some issues with doing that so probably you can help me here.

We have a service which returns some static files(pdfs) and there is authorization required to call that api. So I invoke API using following method:

```html
  download(uri) {
    this.http.get(uri, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Accept':'application/pdf'
      }
    }).subscribe(()=>{});
```

but what this method actually does - it firstly loads content in memory and then displays it in list of loaded by browser files. What I would want to have - instead firstly loading file in browser memory I would want that browser will be responsible for loading that file and displaying progress of download.

Please let me know if you need any additional details.

P.S. service responds with header **Content-Disposition: attachment**

Answer (score 0):

You need actually to use blob since you are using ajax call.
**first install `https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#readme`** then

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

download(uri) {
this.http.get(uri, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
     responseType: 'blob' 
  }
}).subscribe((res)=>{
var blob = new Blob(res, {type: "application/pdf"});
saveAs(blob, "file.pdf");
});
```

- Your back-end **should** return array bytes

UPDATE 
If you want to receive events of download progress you can add `observe: 'events'`
look at [download progress](https://netbasal.com/a-taste-from-the-new-angular-http-client-38fcdc6b359b)

Other Option

- You can can send a first request **ajax** to server and in server side generate random URL can be used one time to download file
- Then use this example and pass the received link in href and trigger click event. like this example

  ```
  function download(filename, link) {
   var element = document.createElement('a');
   element.setAttribute('href', link);
   element.setAttribute('download', filename);

   element.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(element);

   element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
  ```

Comment: actually this is what I would want to avoid as it downloads everything firstly in memory but I would want that browser will be responsible for tracking progress on file download and not my app.

Comment: You can't do this send 'Authorization' header on static file direct, but you can play around by send rest call to API and the controller will check the user if have permission to download the file and return the results as array bytes

Comment: still in this case I will be responsible for downloading file but what I would expect is that browser will start file downloading after sucessful response from the server.

Comment: other option to pass your token as query param  like this `<a [src]="'mypdf.pdf'" [queryParams]="{ token: '12345679'}">` then manual validate your token in the backend.

Comment: that is tricky part... because this is not me supporting this API. So do I understand correctly that there is no other way how to do that with my requirements?